# Pass a generic List to a JSP tag

Tags: java, jsp

I'm using JSP tags to encapsulate reusable front-end logic.

I can successfully pass a complex object `com.example.Product` to a tag, but I'm having trouble passing a `List<Product>` to a tag.

Here is my `product.tag`:

```
<%@ attribute name="product" required="true" type="com.example.Product" %>
<a href="/products/${product.id}/${product.slug}">${product.name}</a>
```

I can use this on a JSP page like so:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="h" %>
<h:product product="${myProduct}"/>
```

Now, I would like to create a tag to display a list of products. I'm stuck on how to describe the type in the attribute declaration:

```
<%@ attribute name="products" required="true" type="???" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<ul>
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
  <li><h:product product="${product}"/></li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

I've tried the following:

- `List<com.example.Product>`
- `java.util.List<com.example.Product>`

Both yield the following error: `Unknown attribute type (java.util.List<com.example.Product>) for attribute products`

I'm sure there's just some syntax for how to describe a generic type in the attribute directive, but I can't find any examples.

Comment: Java Generics don't exist at runtime. The `type="java.util.List"` should work. How exactly does it fail? Please note that your tag file example is missing `c` taglib which may be present in your real code, but is a red herring in your snippet.

Comment: @BalusC I added the c taglib, which I had removed from my code to try to keep things simple. But you're right, best to avoid any red herrings. Writing up more info on the output now...

Comment: Okay. How exactly does `type="java.util.List"` fail? It should work. Unless `${products}` isn't an instance of `java.util.List` of course.  Try removing the `<%@attribute%>` or setting it to `type="java.lang.Object"` and then printing `${products}` and `${products['class'].name}` just to see what it says.

Comment: Nevermind. Sometimes my local Tomcat instance doesn't pick up changes to JSPs unless I wait a few seconds. `java.util.List` does work. Can you add an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to specify the generic type. The `type="java.util.List"` must work. Your concrete problem is caused elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, but I realized that I was sending String not actual Object.
Maybe you had same mistake. :)

Comment: Read the comments on the question.